# GNOME Keyring not remembering auth for autosshfs

Tags: ssh, gnome-keyring, sshfs

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 and using [autosshfs](https://github.com/hellekin/autosshfs), a per user SSHFS automount using user’s SSH config and keys. This works great except that Gnome Keyring isn't remembering the authentication and constantly prompts for the password to the key when remounting (after ssh timeout).

My RSA keys reside inside `~/.ssh` with the very restrictive `0400` permissions. I've added the private keys to the keyring with `ssh-add` and the public keys to `authenticated_keys`. I can confirm that they are in the keyring since they show up when I run `ssh-add -l`.

Snip from `auth.log` looks like this:

```
Oct  5 14:01:34 flax sudo:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=oddy ; COMMAND=/bin/bash -c \/usr\/local\/sbin\/autosshfs-ssh remotehost\.com;
Oct  5 14:13:45 flax sudo:     oddy : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/oddy ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/cat /var/log/auth.log
Oct  5 14:14:51  sudo: last message repeated 2 times
Oct  5 14:17:01 flax CRON[5862]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Oct  5 14:17:01 flax CRON[5862]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Oct  5 14:36:36 flax login[1309]: pam_unix(login:session): session opened for user oddy by LOGIN(uid=0)
Oct  5 14:38:11 flax login[1309]: pam_unix(login:session): session closed for user oddy
```

I can't find anything in there that would suggests that it's failing. SSH:ing to the remote host through console doesn't prompt for a password, so the keyring does work for that specific key, just not together with autosshfs.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Note that autosshfs uses [keychain](http://www.gentoo.org/doc/en/keychain-guide.xml) to set the environment variables s.t. ssh can find the `ssh-agent` and its authentication socket. If you haven't told `keychain` to manage the key you want to use for `sshfs` it will ask for your passphrase. Check the output of `keychain -q --eval`, which is what `autosshfs` will run.

A few more debugging hints from issues I previously fell over:

- I'm assuming your `.ssh/config` specifies which key to use for the remote host?
- Do you have keys in `.ssh` not added to the keychain ssh could possibly offer (and hence ask you to unlock)?
- Did you use the same hostname when you tried logging in on the shell that you use with autosshfs (e.g. you use and alias for autosshfs and tried the full hostname in the shell)?
- Have you verified that `ssh-agent` was still running and still had your keys loaded at the point autosshfs was failing / asking for the passphrase?